# Telerik. Error! The requested URL returned 12030-

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, telerik, entity

I cant get to work my grid using telerik

here's my code:

MODEL

```
public class Office
{
    public int OfficeID { get; set; }
    public string OfficeName { get; set; }
    public string OfficeAddress { get; set; }
}
```

VIEWMODEL

```
public class OfficeViewModel
{
    public int OfficeID { get; set; }
    public string OfficeName { get; set; }
    public string OfficeAddress { get; set; }
}
```

VIEW

```
  @(Html.Telerik().Grid<Office>()
  .Name("Offices")    
  .ToolBar(tb => tb.Insert())
  .DataBinding(binding => binding.Ajax()
  .Select("GetOffice", "Office")
  .Update("UpdateOffice", "Office")
  .Insert("InsertOffice", "Office")
  .Delete("DeleteOffice", "Office"))
  .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(o => o.OfficeID))
  .Columns(cols =>
   {
      cols.Bound(c => c.OfficeID).ReadOnly();
      cols.Bound(c => c.OfficeName).Width(20);
      cols.Bound(c => c.OfficeAddress).Width(70);
      cols.Command(cmd =>
        {
           cmd.Edit();
           cmd.Delete();
        });
   })
)
```

CONTROLLER

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
        return View();
    }

[GridAction]
    public ActionResult GetOffices()
    {
        return View(new GridModel(GetOfficeViewModels()));
    }

 private IQueryable<OfficeViewModel> GetOfficeViewModels()
    {
        return db.Offices
                        .Select(
                        c => new OfficeViewModel
                        {
                            OfficeID = c.OfficeID,
                            OfficeName = c.OfficeName,
                            OfficeAddress = c.OfficeAddress
                        });
    }
```

LASTLY, THE LAYOUT.

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Office", "Index", "Office")</li>
```

please help me solve this problem i have already spent many hours on this. I'm only a beginner :(

Thanks

Comment: whats the problem you are getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fixed now, it should be

```
.Select("GetOffices", "Office")
```

I missed the 's', sorry I'm new at this telerik thing

Thanks